# SQL Subquery with a single table result with NULL

Tags: sql

I have tried to select with sub queries in only a single table. but for some reason i got a NULL result.

The table I have look like this.

```
| id | ItemCode | ItemAmount | Counter  |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | 001      | 1          | Counter-1 |
| 2  | 001      | 1          | Counter-2 |
| 3  | 002      | 2          | Counter-1 |
| 4  | 002      | 2          | Counter-2 |
| 5  | 002      | 1          | Counter-2 |
```

I have tried this SQL :

```
select 
    id,
    itemCode, 
    (select ItemAmount where Counter = 'Counter-1') as 'Count 1 Result',
    (select Counter where Counter = 'COUNTER-1') as 'Count Is 1',
    (select ItemAmount where Counter = 'Counter-2') as 'Count 2 Result',
    (select Counter where Counter = 'COUNTER-2') as 'Count Is 2',
from 
    My_Table
```

and the result I got is :

```
| id | ItemCode | Count 1 Result | Count Is 1 | Count 2 Result | Count Is 2 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 001      | 1               | Counter-1 | NULL           | NULL |
| 2  | 001      | NULL            | NULL      | 1              | Counter-2    |
| 3  | 002      | 2               | Counter-1 | NULL           | NULL |
| 4  | 002      | NULL            | NULL      | 2              | Counter-2    |
| 5  | 002      | NULL            | NULL      | 1              | Counter-2    |
```

As you can see, i got NULL result with the NULL Value. How can i do it with the result like this :

```
| id | ItemCode | Count 1 Result | Count Is 1 | Count 2 Result | Count Is 2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 001      | 1               | Counter-1 | 2              | Counter-2 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 002      | 2               | Counter-1 | 3              | Counter-2 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to make it no NULL value anymore and there is no double Item Code with  the SUM Item Amount if the counter and item code is have the same value.

Is that even possible to do it with one table ? if it is how do i do that. thanks in advance

Comment: add a tag of your dbms

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: @hotfix can you give me an example of how to use tag please.

Comment: @jarlh aren't case is when i want to set something conditionally ? but what i want to do is put the Counter 1 and Counter 2 side by side together. not choose only one by condition.

Comment: @hakimhomecent you already have one tag `SQL`.  edit you post and you can add more tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use *Aggregate function condition* to make it.

Here is SQL-server sample:

```
CREATE TABLE My_Table(
  id INT,
  ItemCode VARCHAR(50),
  ItemAmount INT,
  Counter VARCHAR(50)
);


 INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1, '001', 1 ,'Counter-1');
 INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (2, '001', 1 ,'Counter-2');
 INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (3, '002', 2 ,'Counter-1');
 INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (4, '002', 2 ,'Counter-2');
 INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (5, '002', 1 ,'Counter-2');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY itemCode) id,
    itemCode, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Counter = 'Counter-1' THEN ItemAmount ELSE 0 END) as 'Count 1 Result',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Counter = 'COUNTER-1' THEN Counter END) as 'Count Is 1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Counter = 'Counter-2' THEN ItemAmount ELSE 0 END) as 'Count 2 Result',
    MAX(CASE WHEN Counter = 'COUNTER-2' THEN Counter  END) as 'Count Is 2'
from 
    My_Table
GROUP BY 
    itemCode
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/96677/7/0)**:

```
| id | itemCode | Count 1 Result | Count Is 1 | Count 2 Result | Count Is 2 |
|----|----------|----------------|------------|----------------|------------|
|  1 |      001 |              1 |  Counter-1 |              1 |  Counter-2 |
|  2 |      002 |              2 |  Counter-1 |              3 |  Counter-2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try conditional aggregation, something like:

```
SELECT min(id) id,
       itemcode,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN counter = 'Counter-1' THEN
               itemamount
             ELSE
               0
           END) count1result,
       'Counter-1' countis1,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN counter = 'Counter-2' THEN
               itemamount
             ELSE
               0
           END) count2result,
       'Counter-2' countis2
       FROM my_table
       GROUP BY itemcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not sure what you are expecting with out disturbing your code I have given the query. Implement in your requirement

```
;WITH CTE AS (select 

    itemCode, 
    (select SUM(ItemAmount) where Counter = 'Counter-1') as 'Count 1 Result',
    (select MAX(Counter) where Counter = 'COUNTER-1') as 'Count Is 1',
    (select SUM(ItemAmount) where Counter = 'Counter-2') as 'Count 2 Result',
    (select MAX(Counter) where Counter = 'COUNTER-2') as 'Count Is 2'
from 
    My_table
    GROUP BY 
    itemCode,Counter )

    Select RANK()OVER ( ORDER BY itemcode)Id,
    itemCode,
    MAX([Count 1 Result])[Count 1 Result],
    MAX([Count Is 1])[Count Is 1],
    MAX([Count 2 Result])[Count 2 Result],
    MAX([Count Is 2])[Count Is 2] 
        from  CTE 
    GROUP BY itemCode
```

Answer (score 0):

For the **data retrieval** part the following would give your data,
by grouping on ItemCode and Counter:

```
select
    ItemCode,
    Counter,
    min(Id) as Id,
    sum(ItemAmount) as ItemAmount,
from 
    My_Table
group by ItemCode, Counter

ItemCode  Counter    Id   ItemAmount
========  =========  ===  ==========
001       Counter-1    1           1
001       Counter-2    1           2
002       Counter-1    3           1
002       Counter-2    3           3
```

To display that as so called **pivot** table, rows-to-columns, there are several solutions, one generic SQL solution:

In Modern SQL:

```
select ItemCode,
    ItemAmount filter (where Counter = 'Counter-1') as A1,
    ItemAmount filter (where Counter = 'Counter-2') as A2
from (select
        ItemCode,
        Counter,
        min(Id) as Id,
        sum(ItemAmount) as ItemAmount,
    from 
        My_Table
    group by ItemCode, Counter)
group by ItemCode
```

If `filter` is still not supported in the used SQL:

```
select ItemCode,
    sum(case when Counter = 'Counter-1' then ItemAmount end) as A1,
    sum(case when Counter = 'Counter-2' then ItemAmount end) as A2,
```